# Import/Export file from PHP

Tags: php, download, export-to-csv

I think I wasn't clean in my explanation when I asked my question (the problem).
I have a project PHP, I don't have a local environnement, I'm working on-line: I change my file via Netbeans and I deploy it without tested it locally. My server is of production.My Database (MySQL - phpMyadmin ) in the sever also.
I import the data from my disk into the project. Then PHP exploit it via HighChart. The user can see these data per many choices (Date, city, Customer,..) and finally he can download this final result into file csv.
Here the problem I can't download all the data, for example: in The Turnover display in the Chart 14Million but in the file csv it display a smaller number of turnover.

this following my code:

```
class Export{
    private $_dataIN=[];
    private $_author;
    private $_filepath;

    public function __construct(array $dataIN) {
        $this->_dataIN = $dataIN;
        $this->setFilepath();
        $this->prepareFile();
    }
    public function setFilepath() {
        $date = new \DateTime();
        $this->_filepath='../DATA/ExportFiles/ExportData'.$date->getTimestamp();
    }
    public function prepareFile(){
        $file = fopen($this->_filepath, 'w');
        fputcsv($file, array('Piece', 'Client', 'Libelle Client', 'Facturation','OTP','Typcde','Cdecli','Cdesap','Article','Designation','Dev','Montant_fac_dev_ht','Montant_fac_eur','Avion','Nature','Repsite','Zone','LRU','Contract'),';');        
        foreach ($this->_dataIN as $key => $statement) {
            fputcsv($file, array($statement->getId(), $statement->getCustomerId(), $statement->getCustomerName(), $statement->getDate(), $statement->getOTP(), $statement->getCdetype(), $statement->getCdecustomer(), $statement->getSAPcode(), $statement->getArticle(), $statement->getDesigniation(), $statement->getCurrency(), $statement->getAmount(), $statement->getAmountEur(), $statement->getAircraft(), $statement->getNature(), $statement->getRepsite(), $statement->getZone(), $statement->getLru(),$statement->getContract()),';');
        }
    }

    public  function download() {        

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');//octet-stream' 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($this->_filepath).'.csv'); 
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($this->_filepath) . 'Giga'); //Kilo
        readfile($this->_filepath);
        exit();
```

I hope that this time my explanation is clean and you can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use like this without storing:

```
public function __construct($dataIN = array()) {
    $this->_dataIN = $dataIN;
    $this->prepareFile();
}

public function prepareFile(){

    $header[] = array('Piece', 'Client', 'Libelle Client', 'Facturation','OTP','Typcde','Cdecli','Cdesap','Article','Designation','Dev','Montant_fac_dev_ht','Montant_fac_eur','Avion','Nature','Repsite','Zone','LRU','Contract');        

    $data = array();

    foreach ($this->_dataIN as $key => $statement) {
        $data[] = array($statement->getId(), $statement->getCustomerId(), $statement->getCustomerName(), $statement->getDate(), $statement->getOTP(), $statement->getCdetype(), $statement->getCdecustomer(), $statement->getSAPcode(), $statement->getArticle(), $statement->getDesigniation(), $statement->getCurrency(), $statement->getAmount(), $statement->getAmountEur(), $statement->getAircraft(), $statement->getNature(), $statement->getRepsite(), $statement->getZone(), $statement->getLru(),$statement->getContract());
    }

    $final_data = array_merge($header, $data);

    $this->array_to_csv($final_data, 'report.csv');
}


function array_to_csv($array, $download = "")
{   
    if ($download != "")
    {    
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $download . '"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    }        

    ob_start();
    $f = fopen('php://output', 'w') or show_error("Can't open php://output");
    $n = 0;        
    foreach ($array as $line)
    {
        $n++;
        if ( ! fputcsv($f, $line))
        {
            show_error("Can't write line $n: $line");
        }
    }
    fclose($f) or show_error("Can't close php://output");
    $str = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    if ($download == "")
    {
        return $str;    
    }
    else
    {    
        print "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
        print $str;
    }        
}
```

Comment: It genere an error like this: UndefinedFunctionException in Export.php line 39: Attempted to call function "array_to_csv" from namespace "Floose\Export". Fatal error: Call to undefined function Floose\Export\array_to_csv() in /home/outils/FLOOSE/FlooseDev/src/Export/Export.php on line 39.

Comment: I added it here but in vein: public function __construct(array $dataIN) {
        $this->_dataIN = $dataIN;
        $this->setFilepath();
        $this->prepareFile();
        $this->array_to_csv($array, $download);
    }

Comment: please check prinr_r($this->_dataIN). What are getting over in this.

Comment: I add it in the function _construct ? May be because I called the function "array_csv" before her manipulation ? or no ?

Comment: Yes,I can see, But I want know that the data which you passing at the time of calling class. Did you get or not in constructor? Just check by print in overthere.

Comment: it seems works I Think I dowloaded all the data but the display in the file report.csv is not organise. Also it display a code html like this:     [0] => Floose\Export\Statement Object       
        (       
            [_id:Floose\Export\Statement:private] => 120125255       
            [_customerName:Floose\Export\Statement:private] => SR TECHNICS SWITZERLAND LTD _customerID:Floose\Export\Statement:private] => 467       
            [_date:Floose\Export\Statement:private] => 03-01-2017

Comment: I tihnk the reason from  this print_r($this->_dataIN) or no ?

Comment: I delete  print_r($this->_dataIN), the data in the comment above don't display, but still the code HTML and the data is unorganized. For example two parameters in the same column.

Comment: I think I should delete this : $final_data = array_merge($header, $data); or no ?

Comment: @sirine your data is protected that why you are unable to retrieve data in loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, what you mean exactly by my data is protected ? Which the solution in this case please ?

Comment: @sirine I want to know that what data array are you getting before processing csv. Can you print it over there?