# How to download files from this type of links?

Tags: php, curl

I am developing an application to download some apps. But I can't cross the Google Play store authentication. So I just know the apps name and download from third party website.

I try to use `get_file_content` and `curl`, but I get a error response:

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.

My code:

```
private function download_file($name) {

  $url='https://apkpure.com/snake-off-more-play-more-fun/com.wepie.snakeoff/download?from=details',
  $app_name = $name.'.apk';
  $path = self::DOWNLOAD_DIR;

  set_time_limit ( 0 );

  $url = trim ( $url );
  $curl = curl_init ();
  curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
  curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  $file = curl_exec ( $curl );
  curl_close ( $curl );

  $filename = $path . $app_name;
  $write = @fopen ( $filename, "w" );
  if ($write == false) {
       return false;
  }
  if (fwrite ( $write, $file ) == false) {
       return false;
  }
  if (fclose ( $write ) == false) {
       return false;
  }

  return $app_name;
}
```

Comment: What line is giving this error?

Comment: this is the download link: [click here](https://d0.winudf.com/b/apk/Y29tLndlcGllLnNuYWtlb2ZmXzIwNjRfMjhlNzE0NmU?_fn=U25ha2UgT2ZmIE1vcmUgUGxheSBNb3JlIEZ1bl92Mi4wX2Fwa3B1cmUuY29tLmFwaw&_p=Y29tLndlcGllLnNuYWtlb2Zm&as=3fe1bc6902ed3821fbe5eea4ec65c64558ec6bf0&c=2%7CGAME_ACTION&k=8442623d09902d4ecf5866121f96c02058ef8e5f)

Comment: and for download refer this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/43226862/1676023](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43226862/1676023)

Comment: @Gaurav i use your link, it works. but how can i get the real links from this website?

Comment: @JohnnyYou you have to get html using the link which you have specified. Then domxpath query find that link and then download.

Comment: @Gaurav I am trying ,will reply latter. Thanks!

Comment: @Gaurav Using domxpath query cant find this element. it seem this url console by javascript. and the url is response by a 'iframe' request.funny~

Comment: @JohnnyYou there is `click here` link which have `id='download_link'` try to fetch this.

Comment: Updated code formatting, error message, and tags for readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to get html:

```
$ckfile = tempnam (sys_get_temp_dir(), rand().'cookiename');

$handle = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt ($handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');

/* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
$response = curl_exec($handle);
// response total time
$time = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME);
/* Check for 404 (file not found). */
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($handle);

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
@$dom->loadHTML($response);

$xpath = new DOMXPath ($dom);

$array = array();

$links = $xpath->query ("//div[@class='fast-download-box']//a[@id='download_link']/@href");
$url = "";
foreach ($links as $link)
{
    $url = $link->nodeValue;
    if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        break 2;
    }
}
download_file($url, 'application');
```

for download file:

```
function download_file($link, $filename) {

    $extension = apk;

    $mime = 'application/octet-stream';

    // Generate the server headers
    if( strstr( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE" ) ) {
        header( 'Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'.'.$extension );
        header( 'Expires: 0' );
        header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
        header( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" );
        header( 'Pragma: public' );
    } else {
        header( "Pragma: public" );
        header( "Expires: 0" );
        header( "Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" );
        header( "Cache-Control: private", false );
        header( "Content-Type: ".$mime, true, 200 );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'.'.$extension);
        header( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" );
    }
    readfile( $link );
}
```

Comment: but plz check the function's result , this url is still cant use . compare with the first url you post in this question title answer~

Comment: i also have tried your answer that post in the question"http://stackoverflow.com/a/43226862/1676023" . no useful for this url.

Comment: the problem is , if i only use hte function download_file , it works, and i use the URL="https://d0.winudf.com/b/apk/Y29tLndlcGllLnNuYWtlb2ZmXzIwNjRfMjhlNzE0NmU?_fn=U25ha2UgT2ZmIE1vcmUgUGxheSBNb3JlIEZ1bl92Mi4wX2Fwa3B1cmUuY29tLmFwaw&_p=Y29tLndlcGllLnNuYWtlb2Zm&as=0ca1f9d3baf8d596a962c4d9f5dcee6e58eca8da&c=2%7CGAME_ACTION&k=8442623d09902d4ecf5866121f96c02058ef8e5f"

Comment: but the code you give to me to find the real url is wrong,it cant convert a url to the next function . i fixed the problem ,but the url is not the what i want . focus the useful domain is "w0.winudf.com" the fake domain is "download.apkpure.com".

Comment: did this solve your problem? Because I tried this code and it is running perfectly.

Comment: @JohnnyYou use `break 2` in place of `exit` in foreach loop.

Comment: i use break 2 , reponse is cannot break 2 level~  the domxpath_query function can find the url is "https://download.apkpure.com/b/apk/Y29tLndlcGllLnNuYWtlb2ZmXzIwNjRfMjhlNzE0NmU?_fn=U25ha2UgT2ZmIE1vcmUgUGxheSBNb3JlIEZ1bl92Mi4wX2Fwa3B1cmUuY29tLmFwaw%3D%3D&k=7a48c949c7d5b76c3d10589a970a666f58ef559c&as=aa5d2b239c0b354460d1e71bb1e8a29b58ecb314&_p=Y29tLndlcGllLnNuYWtlb2Zm&c=2%7CGAME_ACTION"

Comment: but the url i need is the website(https://apkpure.com/snake-off-more-play-more-fun/com.wepie.snakeoff/download?from=details) console data , is "https://d0.winudf.com/b/apk/Y29tLndlcGllLnNuYWtlb2ZmXzIwNjRfMjhlNzE0NmU?_fn…0bc0558ecb37a&c=2%7CGAME_ACTION&k=8442623d09902d4ecf5866121f96c02058ef8e5f".

Comment: only less a step to finish it

Comment: @JohnnyYou just a correction use `break 1` instead of `break 2`. And by `str_replace("download.apkpure.com", "d0.winudf.com", $url), ` replace it and then call download function.

Comment: i try to make clear the different of these links, but they are not only different of the domain. only replace this , cant use it.

Comment: I am unable to understand. What actually you want?

Comment: OK. 
download the apk file from the link "https://apkpure.com/snake-off-more-play-more-fun/com.wepie.snakeoff/download?from=details" is what i want.

Comment: yesterday, you give me two functions .right?
the first function is to find the download link from the page , right ?

Comment: but the first function find the "click here" button's link, but this link, cant use      .

Comment: but the download link is unavailable in the second function.

Comment: but i found , when you open the download page , the chrome console a link, this link i can use in the second function(download function).

Comment: from first function you are getting download link and then this link pass to download function. The file get download.

Comment: the first function's result cant use in the second function, the url is faked.

Comment: What exactly you want? File get download internally or you want to get download popup in browser.

Comment: check here my friend http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361127/php-download-files

Comment: how is the function are you calling? You have to pass $url while call function.

Comment: can you send screenshot of your code? I want to see where you put that function

Comment: when you hit controller `domxpath_query` on browser then file gets download or not?

Comment: NO, the first function transfer a url (the 'click here' button's url) to second function. but the second function say 'net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE'.

Comment: Meeting , replay about 30 mins latter.

Comment: ok, Then check `$url` by echo before calling download method. And show me what url are you getting?

Comment: echo $url;exit; result is :https://download.apkpure.com/b/apk/Y29tLndlcGllLnNuYWtlb2ZmXzIwNjRfMjhlNzE0NmU?_fn=U25ha2UgT2ZmIE1vcmUgUGxheSBNb3JlIEZ1bl92Mi4wX2Fwa3B1cmUuY29tLmFwaw%3D%3D&k=5c19876260f531b5c91957407546d07558f0775e&as=2c93ee31f049c417c2b3568252ac590558edd4d6&_p=Y29tLndlcGllLnNuYWtlb2Zm&c=2%7CGAME_ACTION

Comment: whatever ,thank you. thought it doesnt work , but i learned a lot about php save-to-filestream.

Comment: means...i didn't understand

Comment: XD        means i cant download the file directly, i need a web proxy ~

Comment: yeah, I have to setup proxy server.